# C++ Template Function for Vector of Unique Elements

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am trying to create a template function that takes an input vector of type T, by reference, and modifies that vector in such a way that it contains only unique elements:

This is what I have got so far:

```
template<typename T>
void uniqueOnly(vector<T>& vec){
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
  it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  vec.resize( std::distance(vec.begin(),it) );
}
```

However, I am getting a couple of errors when trying to compile, Namely:

> functions.cpp:52:6: error: expected unqualified-id   it =
>   std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());

And

> functions.cpp:53:41: error: unexpected type name 'it': expected
>   expression   vec.resize( std::distance(vec.begin(),it) );

Would someone please be so generous as to decrypt those error messages for me, and point me in the right direction to fix the problem?

Comment: `vec.erase(it, vec.end());` is shorter and equivalent to `vec.resize(std::distance(vec.begin(),it));`

Comment: @aschepler, thanks, but wouldn't that depend on the number of duplicates in the original vector?

Answer (score 3):

Both errors are complaining because `it` is a type, but you're trying to use it as an object.

Take away `typedef` from the declaration of `it` so that you declare an iterator object, not a synonym type for the iterator type.

Or, just:

```
auto it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.resize( std::distance(vec.begin(),it) );
```

Answer (score 1):

you define `it` to be the type `std::vector<T>::iterator`.
so your code won't compile as `it` isn't an iterator it's an iterator type.

```
template <typename T>
void uniqueOnly(std::vector<T>& vec){
  typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator It; // It is the name of a type
  It it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
  vec.erase(it, vec.end());                     // uses aschepler's suggestion
}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. So obvious (Now). Cheers.

Comment: These things happen all the time, it always seems to be that when someone else looks at it they see it right off the bat.